# How can I count the unique numbers in an array without rearranging the array elements?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I am having trouble counting the unique values in an array, and I need to do so without rearranging the array elements.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Nothing wrong with homework... Provided one doesn't just take the answers as they are.
(ie, take the answer, and make it *better*).

Answer (score 20):

If you have .NET 3.5 you can easily achieve this with LINQ via:

```
int numberOfElements = myArray.Distinct().Count();
```

Non LINQ:

```
List<int> uniqueValues = new List<int>();
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; ++i)
{
    if(!uniqueValues.Contains(myArray[i]))
        uniqueValues.Add(myArray[i]);
}
int numberOfElements = uniqueValues.Count;
```

Comment: If this is a homework question, then the answer isn't likel to get him many points but still a good answer in terms of linq.

Comment: The non-linq example is really bad, but let's let Rich B come up with a better solution if it is indeed a homework question. :)

(HINT: How would you avoid having to iterate over the entire array for each item?)

Comment: Let Jarus come up with a better solution, rather. (Why doesn't SO allow one to edit comments!?)

Comment: You can delete comments and re-write. That's what I do.

Comment: You can delete and then re add. Guessing that editing could obscure the flow of the conversation.

Comment: @Arafangion Yeah, generally have to delete and re-state.  I knew what you meant though and that is why I post non optimized solutions for homework related questions, so the poster can think and exercise.

Comment: @Ara: I didn't ask the question.

Comment: You should probably use some kind of hash set instead of a list to avoid O(n^2) performance.

Answer (score 7):

This is a far more efficient non LINQ implementation.

```
        var array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4 };
        // .Net 3.0 - use Dictionary<int, bool> 
        // .Net 1.1 - use Hashtable 
        var set = new HashSet<int>();
        foreach (var item in array) {
            if (!set.Contains(item)) set.Add(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} distinct values. ", set.Count);
```

Comment: Why <int, object> instead of <int, bool>?

Comment: Performance wise they should both be identical, will clean it up to use HashSet so this demo code looks less ugly

Comment: The dictionary contains should be far faster on large arrays than the List contains.

Comment: You don't need to test whether the HashSet contains a value. If it contains, Add() does nothing. Maybe the compiler knows to optimize but you will get a slight performance improvement otherwise.

Comment: It turns out that calling .Add for an item that is already there is slower than calling .Contains ... so it all depends on your input array

Comment: .Add() probably updates the set regardless of whether it contains it or not, since the result will be the same whether it checks for it or just adds it.

Comment: .Contains takes O(n) time, so this solution will take O(n2) time

Answer (score 1):

O(n) running time max_value memory usage

```
boolean[] data = new boolean[maxValue];
for (int n : list) {
   if (data[n]) counter++
   else data[n] = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should only the distinct values be counted or should each number in the array be counted (e.g. "number 5 is contained 3 times")?

The second requirement can be fulfilled with the starting steps of the counting sort algorithm.
It would be something like this:

- build a set where the index/key is
  the element to be counted
- a key is connected to a variable which holds the number of occurences
  of the key element
- iterate the array

  - increment value of key(array[index])

Regards